# X is connected iff every application $f:X\to D$ is constant for every discrete space $D$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

How can I prove that a metric space $X$ is connected if and only if every application $f:X\to D$ is constant for every discrete space $D$?

I already know how to prove that $X$ is connected iff every two-valued function on $X$ is constant, however if I try to prove the problem in analogous way to the last one I need that $f$ be continuous which is not an hypthesis of my problem and the open sets formed in the proof of the last one not necessarily "cover" all the space in the part where every function is constant implies $X$ is connected.

Comment: If you don't assume $f$ to be continuous, the statement is simply not true. Take the map $f\colon [0,1]\to \{\pm 1\}$ such that $f(t) = -1$ if $t\leq \frac12$ and $f(t) = 1$ if $t > \frac12$.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that it had to be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

This is false as written: you're missing the key assumption of *continuity*.

> A metric space is connected if and only if every *continuous* map $f\colon X\to D$ is constant, for every discrete space $D$.

One direction is trivial: suppose $X$ is connected and that $f\colon X\to D$ is continuous, with $D$ a discrete space. If $D$ has one element, then $f$ is constant. If $D$ has at least two elements, consider $x\in X$ and note that $A=f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})$ and $B=f^{-1}(D\setminus\{f(x)\})$ are disjoint open sets in $X$ and $A\cup B=X$. Then…

Conversely, if $X$ is disconnected, take two disjoint open sets $A,B$ witnessing it and consider the map $f\colon X\to\{0,1\}$ where $f(a)=0$ for $a\in A$ and $f(b)=1$ for $b\in B$.

The assumption of continuity cannot be lifted off: consider the map $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$ defined by $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: In the converse why do you take $f:X\to \{0,1\}$ if it's supposed that the range be $D$ and not $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @IesusDaveSanz I can't understand: for the converse, I use a particular discrete space $D=\{0,1\}$, which happens to be a subspace of the reals, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, now I understand why. I didn't realize that as it is for all discrete spaces I could take one in particular. Thank you.

Comment: I guess an "application" is a continuous map.

Comment: @PaulFrost Possibly, but it wouldn't be a common terminology.